# Why do my paragraph boxes under my photos have an invisible link that stretches throughout the width of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want it to be a link that you hover over the box and you can click it only when you do that. This page has the links that you can click even when you step away from the paragraph text. Does that make sense? Here's my code so you can understand it better. BTW I'm a beginner. So don't judge lol INDEX.HTML

Dalexis The Great Critic The Greatest TV Shows of All Time The Shows That Enthrilled Us! Home About Us Contact Us 
This website is devoted to shows that kept us loving the tv series This is the list and believe that this is true! Breaking Bad The Wire The Sopranos Seinfeld Curb Your Enthusiasm © 2014 Dalexis Peguero

HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <section class="section">       
        <ul>
            <li><a href="img/breaking-bad.html"><img src="img/breaking-bad.jpg" alt=""/><p>Breaking Bad</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="The-Wire.html"><img src="img/the-wire.jpg" alt=""/><p>The Wire</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="The-Sopranos.html"><img src="img/the-sopranos.jpg" alt=""/><p>The Sopranos</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="Seinfeld.html"><img src="img/seinfeld.jpg" alt=""/><p>Seinfeld</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="Curb.html"><img src="img/curb.jpg" alt=""/><p>Curb Your Enthusiasm</p></a></li>
             <li>
```

CSS

```
body {

}

/*************************** HEAD ****************************/ body { background-color: #BDB76B }

logo {

max-width:940px;
margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 5%;

}

header { background-color: #d3d3d3; padding: 10px 0 0 0 ; margin: 0 0 35px 0; width: 100%; float: left; text-align: center;

} a { text-decoration: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; outline: none; }

a:visited { color: #15141c; font-weight: 100; }

a:hover { color: #201818;

}

a { list-style: none; } /*************************** BODY ****************************/ body { font-family: 'nunito', sanse-serif;

}

/*************************** HEADER ****************************/

div ul li p { margin 0; padding: 5%; font-size: 0.75em; }

.directory { padding: 0; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 0; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;

}

}

/*************************** NAVIGATION ****************************/

/*************************** SECTION ****************************/

list li a p {

margin 0; padding: 5%; font-size: 0.75em; color: #bdc3c7; }

}

div li { float: left; width: 45%; margin: 2.5%;;

}

div img { max-width: 50%; width: 200px; length : 200px; }

/*************************** fOOTER ****************************/

logo {



 width: 50px;
    height:  50px;
    padding:  5px 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the question now? if the title is the question: your link is around the image AND the paragraph, so they are both clickable and linking to the href target

Comment: Ok so when you hover over the image your mouse will indicate that it's a link. Good! When I hover over the text paragraph it indicates its a link. Another good thing, but when i go to side of my paragraph text under my image it'll indicate that there's a link there too. So i want the link to stop where the paragraph text finishes.

Comment: I edited my answer there you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the behaviour of your `<p>` with this CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
```

You have to add `<br />` after the `<img>` and before the `<p>` to get the `<p>` below the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the link with image and text you just have to add this css.

```
p {
     display:inline-block;
}
```

By doing this the link will not full the entire page width.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the image and the text in the same line use below mentioned CSS for more detail have a look at  the link **http://jsfiddle.net/jai17/uanbrj22/2/**

CSS:

```
div ul li p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    padding: 5%;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 200px;
}
```